# How to use 次 with verbs

Tags: usage, vocabulary

How do I use this with verbs with and without nouns, generally I can't find the grammar

I tried googling and search on YouTube but I can't find anything in deep detail

Comment: Where are you stuck? "I have been there twice" <---> “我去过那两次。” It's plain and straightforward to translate between "time(s)" and 次。

Comment: In things Chinese, I would not use Google, try Baidu, baidu.com Have a look [here](https://www.xuexila.com/zuci/265364.html).

Comment: Hi, can you please elaborate a little? What do you mean with using 次 with verbs? Or using it with or without nouns?

Comment: You can do more exercises and you will understand how to use it in different atmosphere of Chinese sentences.
Like this one,
https://www.echineselearning.com/blog/video-lesson-the-difference-between-ci-and-bian I have differed 次 and 遍 after finishing.

Answer (score 1):

format:

Verb + 了（for perfect tense）+ number + 次 + objective（only with vt.）

for example:

1. 春游了5次
   2、游了3次泳
   3、迟到4次了 = 迟到了4次

Answer (score 1):

- vi了n次，vi过n次，看过几次，去过很多次
- vt过/了obj n次，vt过/了n次obj，过了三次河，打了他三次
- 每次都xxx，每次v都xxx，每次都做得好，次次打架都有你
- 这次、那次：这次办得好，那次病得重，这次中了个奖，那次买的质量高，哪次不是他第一个走？
- 第n次v，最后一次v，我是第几次回答问题了？
- v1一次v2一下，(每)v1一次(就)v2(一下，两个，几个)，催一次做一点，问一句答一句

there's quite a lot of usage of it with verbs. hope these examples help you understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

次 is offen use as quantifier word, it is similar like `time` in english.
The verb usage is like this(`mean stop`):
[image]

Learn more:  https://www.chazidian.com/r_zi_zd6b21/
Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 kinds of usage of the word 次, (1) Cardinal words, 两次，三次。(2) Ordinal words, 第一次，第二次. You can also say 许多次 many times，最后一次 the last time，etc.

For example, 我去过上海三次，第一次去的时候，常常迷路。I have visited Shanghai three times. I often got lost the first time I was there.

Answer (score 0):

去次一号/廁所 - go to the bathroom. 去(go) is the verb, 次 acts as a quantifier that means "a trip", the combined word "去次" means "a trip to". 一号/廁所(bathroom) is the noun.

- 讓我們去次上海 - Let's make a trip to Shanghai.

俗語道"去芜存菁" - 去除雜亂，保留菁華. Similarily, we can say "去次存精" - 去除次品，保留精華. (Eliminate the inferior items, and only keep the best item). Note that 去 and 存 are verbs, and 次 and 精 are adjectives.

Answer (score -1):

次 usually have serveral meanings in native user's daily life.

1.Quantifier：一次、兩次、三次、N次、無數次。

2.Second-rate、Secondary、Order、take second place....

i.e.

a) 次級品、次等

b) 次要

c) 項次、次序

d) 我認為最棒的籃球員是麥可喬登，Kobe【次之】！